# Fastest way to retrieve data from SQLite database

Tags: python, sql, numpy, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT timestamp FROM stockData");
times = np.array(c.fetchall())
times = times.reshape(len(times))

buys = []

sells = []

def price(time):
    c.execute("SELECT aapl FROM stockData WHERE timestamp = :t", {'t':time});
    return c.fetchone()[0]

def trader(time):
    p = float(price(time))
    if(p < 186):
        buys.append(p)
    if(p > 186.5):
        sells.append(p)

vfunc =  np.vectorize(trader)


vfunc(times[:1000])
```

This takes about a minute to execute, the reason I see for this is because I am inefficiently calling specific data points from my SQLite DB. I realize I could get around this by calling all relevant data points with something like the following:

```
SEARCH aapl FROM stockData WHERE aapl < 186;
```

But I am dead set on having my code loop through all timestamps one by one, as I want to maintain proper chronology.

My database is about 5 million rows long, thus the current method is not feasible. How can I most efficiently loop through and retrieve this data?

Comment: What do you mean by proper chronology? Do you have indexes set properly?

Comment: By chronology I simply mean I want to execute my trading function moving forwards in time, while say ```SEARCH aapl FROM stockData WHERE aapl < 186;``` would gather all relevant prices at once

Comment: That makes no sense. If you need a limited number of records, use a proper WHERE clause with an ORDER BY to sort them as you need them sorted. *I know I'm inefficiently doing something, but I am dead set on doing that thing I know is wrong. Please help me fix it.* is silly. Stop doing what you know is wrong, and learn to properly write your SQL.

Comment: Fair enough, but in the above example the when to buy and when to sell conditions are very simple and can thus be easily expressed in SQL. However when a neural network is applied it would make more sense to loop through the array and apply it one by one

Comment: I am not sure about your reasons of doing the way you are, but you can try creating an index over your timestamp column.

Comment: Please show the table definition.